# Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined'. React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Following is the code that I am using. I am getting an error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined`. I also want to `dispatch` an action.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
let SearchBar = ({ dispatch }) => {
    let input
    return (
       <div>
           <form>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search"  />
              <p>
                 <input type="checkbox" />
                 {' '}
                 Free
              </p>                
           </form>
       </div>
   )
}

SearchBar = connect()(SearchBar)
export default SearchBar()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things I notice immediately with your code example:

First of all the `connect` function requires some parameters in the first parenthesis, even if that parameter is a `null`, also I don't think you need the parentheses on the export line. Try replacing those last two lines with something like this:

```
export default connect(null)(SearchBar);
```

see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in passing and retreiving the `dispatch` from `connect`. As `connect` without any parameters will return only the `dispatch`

However the problem is in the way you are exporting the component

```
export default SearchBar();
```

You don't need `()` after SearchBar and one more thing. For clarity you can use a different name like

```
var search = connect()(SearchBar)
export default search;
```

or you can do it in a single step like

```
export default connect()(SearcBar);
```

The later is a shorthand for the same thing as the former.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

**We can add mapStateToProps inside the connect also.**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  uData: state
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

We do not need to give null inside the connect().

I believe it may help some of you.